# Java - Errors when using .txt files in .jar

Tags: java, file, jar

When I try and load up a .txt file in my code, I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Program.jar!\test\foo.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

My code for loading these files is this:

```
    try {
        String path = getClass().getResource(file).getPath();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        ...
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not read file!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

And the string I load into the method is this:

```
foo.txt
```

Even though I've checked many times, the file exists in that exact path, yet my program still can't find it. And why is there an exclamation mark at the end of Program.jar? Is it important?

Thank you to anyone who helped answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you launch it out of jar in console, you better access your resource as a `InputStream` and process it the desired way. When you enter the actual path(especially not relative) - you are trying to get to the file that is *INSIDE* the jar, which is wrong.

Here's close (pseudo) code for your problem:

```
InputStream resource = ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/test/foo.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource));
//do some stuff
resource.close();
reader.close();
```

The exclamation mark is a separator the JVM uses to note the `.jar` file in the path.